# Pentaho 5.3.00 Installation to a client Work station

Tags: kettle

I am trying to get Pentaho  version 5.3 installed on my workstation laptop.  My company has the Enterprise edition.  What licences do I have to get?  Can I get copy of licenses from another client work station or I have to get a copy from original server machine?  Can I install the 3.5 edition online and then add the licenses files? or I have to request from system admin to get the `pentaho` installed?

Answer (score 0):

If your company is using Pentaho EE version, i guess there would be a single license file for all the components based on the subscription. Though i am not sure about your company's policy and licensing, i guess you can use the same license either from client n/w or master server.*(note i am assuming you have the permission to use company's license in your local workstation)*

I am assuming

> installing online

means installing Pentaho in a different server and installing the license. Yes you can do the same. You may read [this doc](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0P0/0U0/060) on installing the license.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer